# 'noexec' option on NTFS under Windows?

Tags: windows, permissions, mount, ntfs

Is there equivalent filesystem option on Windows like 'noexec' mount option on Linux? Is it the same if I set "Read" permission, but unset "Read & Execute" permisson on root directory (whole drive)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that Noexec is a bit more specialised than that, however, if you clicked on the Advanced tab in security, then change objects through that, you have a lot more control

If you disable write abilities, you may be able to achieve something similar to what Noexec does, so it will still let programs run, but disable them from doing any sort of changes / writes.

[image]

As for your comment - you can manually add permissions for just folders -

[image]

Comment: Hm, it is not about writing, it is about executing. I want to know if I can disable any kind or possibility of running programs from data drive/partition, including not to be able to create it's own subdirectory and set execute permission on it. So user must be able to read and write, but not execute any programs, including BATs.

Comment: You may have problems as some programs need to be able to write. If I was you, I would look in to using the guest account as this should prevent anyone from making system wide changes.

Comment: 1) The picture above lists `Traverse folder / execute file`. 2) It is possible to create ACLs that would only apply to files, not folders. 3) "Deny" ACLs take precedence.

Comment: It is possible to add your own permission and select folders only - http://i48.tinypic.com/wk1fmh.jpg